# how to define the type of an observer in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Typescript is asking me to type my observer variable :

```
Observer.create(observer: whatTypeShouldIUse => /* do things with observer */)
```

I tried using the `Observer` class or interface from the rxjs library, but it's a generic type.

What type should I put for my observer ? I put `Observer<any>` for now...

Comment: Can you show your complete code (the comment saying do things with observer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you didn't find a solution yet.
First, you must import both Observer and Observable libraries.

`import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';`

Following your question, we do something like this:

```
Observable.create( (observer: Observer<JSON>) => {
    /* do things with observer */
    observer.next(data); //data - Must be a JSON object
    observer.complete();
})
```

Note that the observer type argument is the type of the `observer.next(data)`.

Comment: As of Angular6 the imports will be:
```import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
```

Comment: As of RxJS 6.5.5 `import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs'`

Comment: I need to emit a different type than the one I'm receiving, is there any way of doing that ?